# Rstudio shiny collapsible sidePanel

Tags: r, shiny

I want to maximise the usable screen width of the `mainPanel` for an Rstudio shiny webpage.

In my webpage, the `sidePanel` is used to select parameters to visualise the results in the `mainPanel`.

I would like to know what can I do to maximise the usable space in `mainPanel`.

For example, I would like to have a "collapse/expand" option for the `sidePanel`, so that when collapsed, the entire width of the window is used by `mainPanel`.

Any ideas?

EDITED:

It turns out `sidePanel` is a bit tricky, but I can do two different `bootstrapPage`, and have the one on top for selections that affect the one in the bottom. Then have a collapsible button for it. I'll turn it into an answer unless someone has a more elegant one.

Comment: I haven't seen anything about a collapsable sidebarPanel. Perhaps you can get some inspiration for an alternative from the new [layout features](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/wiki/Shiny-Application-Layout-Guide) in the the development version of Shiny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only a partial solution but ... if you wrap the div below around the content or your sidebarPanel

```
div(id = "demo", class = "collapse in", 

)
```

and then put a button in your main panel as follows

```
HTML("<button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#demo'>simple collapsible</button>"),
```

you can collapse the content of the sidebarPanel. This doesn't expand the main panel to take up all the screen however.

Comment: Ok, this would actually be useful if I then had the sidebar as a collapsible header, changing the question.

Comment: I think so. If your sidebar had an id (would the class work?) then the whole think may collapse. I am thinking this might require using an [HTML ui](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#html-ui). Another idea might be to put a condition before the sidebar, linked to an action button. Not tested.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could work with a toggle-button (e.g. named "set parameters") which opens or closes a `conditionalPanel`. Such panel then disappears or pops-up when needed. 
See: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.13.2/conditionalPanel.html