# Rstudio shiny maximise width of mainPanel for 1920x1080 screen

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I've got an Rstudio shiny webpage with a `sidePanel` and a `mainPanel`, and I want to [maximise the usable space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21699219/719016) for the `mainPanel` on a 1920x1080 screen.

Even if I use this in `gvisTable`:

```
gvisTable(tabData,options=list(height='100%',width='100%'))
```

There is still about 200px unused by the `mainPanel` on the right hand side of the screen.
Any ideas why this might be happening? Is there an upper limit on width for `mainPanel`?

Comment: @Llopis indeed this is possibly a duplicate, but I wanted to be precise in saying what I am trying to do here and hitting what looks like a but, and the overall goal in the other question.

Comment: mainPanel is nothing but a div with the span8 class, I think.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent is right. Try putting .span4 { max-width: 280px; }
and .span8 { max-width: 1000px; } in your css file and play around with the numbers to see if you can get the right fit.

Comment: I've tried with span8 10000px, but still it is still not using all the space on the right hand side. Do I smell a bug?